# How to assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'UIView?'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, tableview

I'm having issues assigning "user-chosen" images to tableViewCells - and tableview backgrounds. I get the error 'Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'UIView?'.

Fx. When I write the following, to try and get the image that the user chose, shown in a specific cell:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Diary1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = allDiaries[indexPath.row].diaryName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = allDiaries[indexPath.row].diaryQuestion
    cell.backgroundView = UIImage(data: newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data())

    return cell
}
```

Also another place I get the same error, when writing this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.backgroundView = UIImage(data: (newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data()))
}
```

So I guess when working with tableView' backgrounds, you have to know how to convert from UIImageView to UIView.

Anybode knows how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a `UIImageView` instance containing the `UIImage`, then set that imageView to the `backgroundView` property, which will work, since `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: (newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data())))
tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

Then do the same in `cellForRowAt` (bear in mind that I changed `newDiary` to `allDiaries[indexPath.row]` since you'd get the same background image for all cells otherwise):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: allDiaries[indexPath.row].diaryTheme)
cell.backgroundView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign `UIImage`, not `UIImageView`. You have to create `UIImageView` with the image and then you'll be able to set it as a background view

```
cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(data: newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UIColor` property to set the `backgroundColor` of `UIView`.

```
public init(patternImage image: UIImage)
```

**Code:**

```
if let image = UIImage(data: newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data()) {
    tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image)
}
```

In TableViewCell

```
if let image = UIImage(data: newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data()) {
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with back ground color and same for image.

```
       tableView.backgroundView.backgroundcolor = color.patterneImage(UIImage(data: (newDiary?.diaryTheme ?? Data())))
```